# run time error 1004 general odbc error refresh backgroundquery false

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a working VBA code which runs as:

```
wsEnd.Select

Range("A:AQ").Delete

        strSQL = "Select *
        strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [XXX].[ABCCustomer] As A"
        strSQL = strSQL & " Left join"
        strSQL = strSQL & " (Select * "
        strSQL = strSQL & " From [XXX]..[ABCCustomer]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " where LineageId = '123' ) B"
        strSQL = strSQL & " on a.product = b.product and a.[StartDate] = b.[StartDate]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " where (a.EndDate <> b.EndDate)"
        strSQL = strSQL & " and a.NewEndDate is NULL AND B.NewEndDate IS NULL"
        strSQL = strSQL & " and a.Id = '456"
        strSQL = strSQL & " order by b.ProductType"

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXX\SQL01;UID=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=2007 Microsoft  Office system;WSID=XXX;DATA" _
        ), Array("BASE=master")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_XXX_C"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End with
```

I have two other scripts starting after the End With but inside the same sub all using the same VBA just different SQL, which all work perfectly fine.

Then I have this very annoying forth, which is causing my a real headache, that goes as follows:

```
        strSQL = "Select *
        strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [XXX].[ABCCustomer] As A"
        strSQL = strSQL & " Left join"
        strSQL = strSQL & " (Select * "
        strSQL = strSQL & " From [XXX]..[ABCCustomer]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " where Id = '123' ) B"
        strSQL = strSQL & " on a.product = b.product and a.[StartDate] = b.[StartDate]"
        strSQL = strSQL & " where (a.EndDate = b.EndDate)"
        strSQL = strSQL & " and a.NewEndDate is Not NULL AND B.NewEndDate not NULL"
        strSQL = strSQL & " and a.Id = '456"
        strSQL = strSQL & " order by b.Product"

        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXX\SQL01;UID=;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;WSID=XXX;DATA" _
        ), Array("BASE=master")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_XXX_D"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

When running the code, the first three come back fine but the forth says

> run time error 1004 general odbc error

and stops the code at `backgroundquery=false`.

I have lifted the SQL code into SQL and it works perfectly fine there  and have even tried running it on a separate excel document and that doesn't give any joy.

The VBA is copy and pasted and only the list object table name is changed i.e. from C to D

I have tried to change `backgroundquery:=false` to `background:=refresh`, this works but I get a message saying

> run time error 1004 This operation cannot be done because the data is refreshing in the background.

Comment: why are you resetting the variable value each line?

Comment: Hi Are you refering to each strSQL = strSQL &?  If so nothing more than to keep it easy to read through for colleaques etc.  Other than that no other reason.

Comment: Just remarque: you are missing closing quotation mark after "Select * which makes the rest of code wrongly formated.

Comment: Hi Radek. You are absolutely correct, well spotted ☺. However I have changed various parts of the example provided to something slightly more generic as the select statement goes on a while.  Please take my word that the unaltered code has the " at the end. I have literally copied and pasted the sql bit into sql and it works perfectly fine. I feel the error is not the sql but something else. Any further ideas are more than welcome

Answer (score 1):

The error went away after a computer reset.  Really sorry, but thanks for all those who responded.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question.  But it is relevant, since the reason for writing it like this was to make it easier to read.

Original Code:  This does a nice job of lining up the characters to read the statement, but is redundant by defining the value of strSQL for every line item.

```
strSQL = "Select *
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [XXX].[ABCCustomer] As A"
strSQL = strSQL & " Left join"
strSQL = strSQL & " (Select * "
strSQL = strSQL & " From [XXX]..[ABCCustomer]"
strSQL = strSQL & " where LineageId = '123' ) B"
strSQL = strSQL & " on a.product = b.product and a.[StartDate] = b.[StartDate]"
strSQL = strSQL & " where (a.EndDate <> b.EndDate)"
strSQL = strSQL & " and a.NewEndDate is NULL AND B.NewEndDate IS NULL"
strSQL = strSQL & " and a.Id = '456"
strSQL = strSQL & " order by b.ProductType"
```

Modified:  Aside from the color formatting getting lost in translation.  This tells anyone reading it that the variable is getting set once and eliminates redundant characters to have to scan over.

```
strSQL = "Select * " & _
         "FROM [XXX].[ABCCustomer] As A " & _
         "Left join " & _
         "(Select * " & _
         "From [XXX]..[ABCCustomer] " & _
         "where LineageId = '123' ) B " & _
         "on a.product = b.product and a.[StartDate] = b.[StartDate] " & _
         "where (a.EndDate <> b.EndDate) " & _
         "and a.NewEndDate is NULL AND B.NewEndDate IS NULL " & _
         "and a.Id = '456 " & _
         "order by b.ProductType"
```

Comment: Always happy to pick up new bits of info, so thanks very much.  Howewver yes the problem remains.  For anyone reading I have been told to attempt to clear the cache in the script.  Does this make sense to anyone and how do I proceed.  If it makes any difference the connection is to SQL Server Management Studio.  Thanks

Comment: I wish I could help you more on the SQL connection.  I just recently started using it and haven't used it with Excel yet.   On the code above:  I think it is less demanding, not that a few characters are hard to deal with, but it doesn't have to read the previous value every time it adds more text to the variable.  As each line adds, it gets exponentially more demanding.  Again no big deal for a few lines of strings, but in theory...  it's setting the variable once vs setting it 11x and reading it 10x with growing length every time.  me = nerd here..